# Simple JavaScript DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, dom

Could anyone please tell me what is wrong with this code? I am trying to create a table from stratch and add ten rows and cells to it. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var cargar = function () {
            var tabla = document.createElement("TABLE");
            document.body.appendChild(tabla);
            var cebreado = function () {
                console.log("Inicio" + a);
                for (var a = 0; a > 10; a++) {
                    tabla.appendChild(document.createElement("TR"));
                    console.log("Hola" + a);
                    for (var b = 0; b > 10; b++) {
                        tabla.appendChild(document.createElement("TD"));
                    }
                }
            }
            ;
            return cebreado;
        }
        ;
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="cargar()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the returned function is not called, replace "return cebreado;" with "cebreado();"

Comment: your table is going to be made wrong as you are not adding your td elements to your tr elements

Comment: these for loops are not going to loop, because 'a > 10' is false; same for b > 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a couple of things wrong:

- You do not call the function `cebreado`, you simply refer to it
- Both you for loops had `>` when it shold be `<`
- You were not appending the `TD` into `TR`, but to the table itself.

Here is your code working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var cargar = function () {
            var tabla = document.createElement("TABLE");
            document.body.appendChild(tabla);
            var cebreado = function () {
                console.log("Inicio" + a);
                for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
                    tabla.appendChild(document.createElement("TR"));
                    console.log("Hola" + a);
                    for (var b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
                        tabla.lastChild.appendChild(document.createElement("TD"));
                    }
                }
            }
            ;
            return cebreado();
        }
        ;
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="cargar()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this : http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/nt3sd8dw/

```
        var cargar = function () {
            var tabla = document.createElement("TABLE");
            document.body.appendChild(tabla);
            var cebreado = function () {

                for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
                    console.log("Inicio" + a);
                    var tr = document.createElement("TR");
                    tabla.appendChild(tr);
                    console.log("Hola" + a);
                    for (var b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
                        var td = (document.createElement("TD"));
                        tr.appendChild(td);
                        var text = document.createTextNode("Hello");
                        td.appendChild(text);
                    }
                }
            }
            ;
            return cebreado();
        }
        ;
cargar();
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed in the code and why?

Comment: the loops for are:  a < 10 and b < 10, to create the elements

Comment: That's the only change?

Answer (score 0):

Miglio answered it already.
What you can do, too, is change onload="cargar()" to onload="cargar()()"

Example:

```
function cargar() {
    function cebreado() {
     alert("x");   
    }
    return cebreado;   
}


cargar()();
```

The final behaviour will be the same, but they are different things.